# Agrupar DataTable VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Saludos a la comunidad.

Tengo una consulta con respecto a la agrupación de un DataTable, pasa que tengo el siguiente DataTable:

[image: foto1]

Requeriría hacer algo como lo siguiente:

[image: FOTO2]

Donde cuando haga clic en el checkbox del nuevo `NroOrden` seleccione todo su grupo; lo que estuve intentado es lo siguiente:

```vb
.Columns("NroOrden").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
```

Pero lo anterior, no funciona y no tengo mucha experiencia en VB.NET. Espero puedan apoyarme. Saludos a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado. Al parecer es una función MERGE que es "estándar" en muchos casos, se puede encontrar en varios foros como en este también.

> Lo que hace realmente no es agrupar sino que elimina las líneas de las celdas de los valores repetidos (la columna por la que quieres agrupar) y luego pareciera un efecto de agrupamiento por esa columna. Pero todo es un efecto visual.

Se las dejo a fin de que a alguien le sirva:

```vb
Private Sub dgvNeumaticos_CellPainting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DgvNeumaticos.CellPainting
        If BtnVistaPorFacturar.Checked Then
            If DgvNeumaticos.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "NroOrden" AndAlso e.RowIndex <> -1 Then

                Using gridBrush As Brush = New SolidBrush(DgvNeumaticos.GridColor), backColorBrush As Brush = New SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor)

                    Using gridLinePen As Pen = New Pen(gridBrush)
                        ' Clear cell   
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds)

                        ' Draw line (bottom border and right border of current cell)   
                        'If next row cell has different content, only draw bottom border line of current cell   
                        If e.RowIndex = DgvNeumaticos.Rows.Count - 1 OrElse
                            (e.RowIndex < DgvNeumaticos.Rows.Count - 2 AndAlso DgvNeumaticos.Rows(e.RowIndex + 1).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString() <> e.Value.ToString()) Then
                            e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1)

                        End If

                        ' Draw right border line of current cell   
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom)

                        ' draw/fill content in current cell, and fill only one cell of multiple same cells   
                        If Not e.Value Is Nothing Then
                            If e.RowIndex > 0 AndAlso DgvNeumaticos.Rows(e.RowIndex - 1).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString() = e.Value.ToString() Then
                            Else
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(CType(e.Value, String), e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds.X + 2, e.CellBounds.Y + 5, StringFormat.GenericDefault)
                            End If
                        End If

                        e.Handled = True
                    End Using
                End Using
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Resultado final:

[image: finalResult]